# Make a htaccess rule change the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Sorry if this has already been asked here, but I haven't found it through looking yet.

I've been asked to remove the `/page` on our site, and just make it go to the homepage instead. This is easy enough to do in PHP, but I'd rather use my .htaccess file if I can (to learn it better mostly).

In PHP I'd do (some psuedo code)

```
if($urlIsSlashPage){
    header('Location: /');
    die();
}
```

Is something like that possible to port to my .htaccess file?

I did have this,

```
RewriteRule     ^page/$     /   [NC,L]
```

And whilst that did show the home page, the URL in the address bar stayed as /page, I want that to display just / instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a redirect.

```
RewriteRule     ^page/?$     http://www.domain.com/   [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Perfect! I tried `Redirect 301 /page /`, but that through me errors. I'll accept when SO lets me.